# How does Oracle database know the global database name and the location of database files merely from ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID?

Tags: database, oracle, file

How does Oracle database know the global database name merely from ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID?

My `ORACLE_SID` is `foosid` and my database name is `foogdn`. In fact, the global database name is `foogdn.example.com`. This is demonstrated in the shell and sqlplus session below.

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=foosid
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/home/ora/app/ora/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
$ "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus" / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Aug 2 12:20:19 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  419430400 bytes
Fixed Size          2925120 bytes
Variable Size         285216192 bytes
Database Buffers      125829120 bytes
Redo Buffers            5459968 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> select * from global_name;

GLOBAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOOGDN.EXAMPLE.COM

SQL> select name from v$controlfile;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/control01.ctl
/home/ora/app/ora/fast_recovery_area/foogdn/control02.ctl

SQL> select name from v$datafile;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/system01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/sysaux01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/undotbs01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/pdbseed/system01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/users01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/pdbseed/sysaux01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/pdborcl/system01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/pdborcl/sysaux01.dbf
/home/ora/app/ora/oradata/foogdn/pdborcl/pdborcl_users01.dbf

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Two questions:

1. How did the database figure out that the `GLOBAL_NAME` for `ORACLE_SID=foosid` is `foogdn.example.com`? The only pieces of clues I provided were `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME` and then started the database. Then the database seems to have figured out on its own that the global database name is foogdn.example.com. How did it do that? Where does it store the mappings of `ORACLE_SID` to `GLOBAL_NAME`?
2. How did the databae figure out the location of the database files? Where is this information stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Example.com`(logical location of your DB) is the value of `db_domain` parameter. `foogdn` is the database's name - value of `db_name` parameter. Values of `db_name` and `db_doman` make up global database name.  Both `db_domain` and `db_name` are stored in either or both `spfile<SID>.ora` and/or `init[<SID>].ora` files. Moreover, database name is stored in the control file(s) and in the header of each datafile along with `DBID`.

The basic structure is:

You specify oracle SID (system identifier) which is used to locate an initialization parameter file whether it's a server parameter file (`spfile<sid>.ora`) or a text initialization parameter file `init<sid>.ora`. `CONTROL_FILES` parameter in the IPF(initialization parameter file) points to the location of control file(s) which contains information about data , redo log, and other file's location.

[Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/toc.htm)